# How do I permanently show my dashboard on a separate monitor?

Tags: display, dashboard

I work in multi monitor setup.

I have some important information available in the dashboard and want it to be always visible on one of the monitor.

Is there a way (w/ external software or not) to do so?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a built in function to do this. You have to look for an external tool, but i think there will be no such tool, though.